# AudioCache is dead, long live Sources

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I want to add an Audio player in flutter, but for any Audio player package show this text in Audio Cash part:

[image]

so how can I add an Audio player in my application?

Comment: you can use this [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

Comment: Yeah I have used it , but I saw this text too!

Comment: it is telling that they updated the version to `audioplayers 1.0.1`.

Comment: These guide for them who are interested in migrating to v1.